# Apply filters like ng-repeat, but without ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat:

```
  <tr data-ng-repeat="worktime in workTimesFiltered = (worktimes | filter:{ customerId : customerFilter } | filter:{ projectId : projectFilter } | dateRangeFilter:startDateFilter:endDateFilter)">
                <td>{{worktime.customerName}}</td>
                <td><em>{{worktime.employee}}</em>
  </tr>
```

That's linked to a few drop down filters like customerId and ProjectId.

No I need to render some graphs using Google Charts.

I though I had the way, but $watch -ing the drop downs and then using workTimesFiltered for the data for the graphs.

Now I realise that this doesn't work because I am getting the filtered list before the latest filtering is done (as soon as the select box changes).

I'm looking for something like ng-repeat, that I can apply the filters to, but call a function instead (that will render the graphs).

If this is the right approach, how do I do that, otherwise, what should I do?

Comment: try `<tr data-ng-repeat="worktime in workTimesFiltered = (worktimes | filter:{ customerId : customerFilter, projectId : projectFilter } | dateRangeFilter:startDateFilter:endDateFilter)">`

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly inject the $filter service function, and you can then use that $filter to get any filter function present on the module (or its dependencies).

Here is an example taken from [Angular's API Reference - $filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter)

```
angular.module('filterExample', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
     $scope.originalText = 'hello';
     $scope.filteredText = $filter('uppercase')($scope.originalText);
});
```

So you can basicly do all your filtering on your controller, or better yet, create a service that will handle the filtering for you.